# Roughly how fast can a constant current LED circuit ramp to 1A without EMI issues?

Tags: arduino, led, emc, led-driver, interference

I have a constant current circuit supplying a 1A LED for a carefully controlled strobing application; for my application the LED needs to turn ON (*no dimming*) for ~1ms and then OFF (*fully off*), at a rate of ~10 times per second.

The strobing is externally triggered, and I had originally expected negligible latency (clock cycles, LED rise time, etc... I figured a few microseconds, which I could ignore). But now I am worried about failing EMI testing due to the sharp current rise when switching ON to 1 amp.

For a typical* constant-current circuit, is there a rule of thumb for ramping the current to turn the LED fully ON without running into horrible EMI issues? How fast can I turn this LED fully ON without making a mess? A few microseconds? A few milliseconds?

*I know "typical" isn't very helpful... I'm really trying to get a very broad sense of reasonable ranges.

Comment: I'm no expert, but wouldn't this be highly dependent upon the circuitry itself and also how it is routed and constructed?

Comment: You have a non-constant undefined circuit operating at 10 Hz 1% d.c. near undefined sensors or receivers with perhaps 1A/us slew rates going into undefined capacitance, inductance and voltage with undefined unbalanced cable and undefined ground shift and an undefined slew rate of the switch. But transient current can be computed as Ic=C dV/dt with about 100 pF/m typ. cable.  What could possibly go wrong ? Nothing or anything depends on everything you haven't told us.  Do you care if you hear a ticking sound on your AM radio?

Comment: Excellent points! Clearly too generic a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the return current from the LED largely occupies the same spatial co-ordinates as the forward current then magnetic fields pretty much disappear at any distance more than a couple of feet so I wouldn't be worried about this. Like Jonk said in his comment, it's highly dependent on routing and construction.

If the connections to the LED are very long (centimetres or more) and you had a very fast rise time (nano seconds) then you might start creating an antenna effect that could produce a level of EMI that could fail a legislative test but, again, as Jonk said in his comment, this a a construction and routing phenomenon.

In short; keep connections short and keep them spatially very close. If there's a way of driving the LED that permits slew rate limiting then use it but, don't bust a gut if there isn't.

Comment: Thank you for these broad guiding principles, much appreciated :)